# PHP XML parsing issue

Tags: php, sql, xml

I want to be able to parse a SQL database with PHP to output an XML, however I cannot get it to show the table name and all of it's contents. I could use some help, here is my code without login information:
I have defined the db server,mdb user and pass, and db name; should anything else be defined?

```
<?php
// connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS)
   or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

// select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $dbhandle)
   or die("Could not select data");

// return all available tables 
$result_tbl = mysql_query( "SHOW TABLES FROM "DB_NAME, $dbhandle );

$tables = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_tbl)) {
   $tables[] = $row[0];
}

$output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
$output .= "<schema>";

// iterate over each table and return the fields for each table
foreach ( $tables as $table ) {
   $output .= "<table name=\"$table\">";
   $result_fld = mysql_query( "SHOW FIELDS FROM "$table, $dbhandle );

   while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result_fld) ) {
      $output .= "<field name=\"$row1[0]\" type=\"$row1[1]\"";
      $output .= ($row1[3] == "PRI") ? " primary_key=\"yes\" />" : " />";
   }

   $output .= "</table>";
}

$output .= "</schema>"; 

// tell the browser what kind of file is come in
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// print out XML that describes the schema
echo $output;

// close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: I get the table name but no content displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use standard php class XmlWriter for this one.
Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

Comment: Do you know how I would output all data in the table without declaring each and every column? There are over 20.

Comment: You can use the same loop like in your code but instead of $output .= "<field name=\"$row1[0]\" type=\"$row1[1]\""; use methods startElement(), writeAttribute() and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result_tbl = mysql_query( "SHOW TABLES FROM "DB_NAME, $dbhandle );
                                             ^^^---typo

$result_fld = mysql_query( "SHOW FIELDS FROM "$table, $dbhandle );
                                             ^^^---typo
```

You've got at least two typos in your queries. Most likely you want this:

```
$result_tbl = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM " . DB_NAME, $dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
and
$result_fld = mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM $table", $dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note the concatenation operator (`.`) on the first one, and the addition of `or die(...)`. Never assume a query succeeds. even if the query string itself is syntactically correct, there's far too many OTHER reasons is could fail to NOT check for an error condition.

Comment: I get this error as a output now: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table name here' at line 1

Comment: what's the generated query statement look like? `$sql = "..."; mysql_query($sql) or die("Error " . mysql_error() . $sql);`